# Does $X_n = O_P(a_n)$ and $a_n \to 0$ imply $X_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, convergence, asymptotics

My attempt at this is:

$$X_n = O_P(a_n) \implies P(|X_n| > C a_n) < \epsilon$$

for some $0 < C < \infty$

Then taking the limit inside the probability, we get

$$P(\lim_{n \to \infty} |X_n| > 0) < \epsilon$$

Comment: As a general rule, you can't just take the limit inside the probability operator.  (Indeed, that is the distinction between convergence in probability and almost-sure convergence.)  Consequently, you will either need to justify this step from some theorem, or find a counter-example where it does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication does not hold. Suppose that $a_n = \frac 1 n$, that each $X_n$ follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac 1 n$, and that the $X_n$ are independent.

Then by the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result), the probability that infinitely many of the $X_n$ take value $1$ is $1$. So we don't have almost sure convergence.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that makes sense.

A follow-up question ... The particular problem I'm solving actually is in the form of $X_n = \max_{i = 1, ..., n} |Y_n^{(i)}|$ where $Y_n = \begin{bmatrix} Y_n^{(1)} & \cdots & Y_n^{(n)} \end{bmatrix}^\top$. Would the $\max_i$ allow me to state almost sure convergence?

Comment: It isn't clear how the stochastic boundedness condition from your original question transfers to this follow-up. Maybe post it as its own question.

Comment: Alright. But I could still at least say $X_n$ converges in probability, right?

Comment: I agree that $X_n$ converges in probability in your original question.